# how to set multiple materials using array in the submesh of an object

Tags: unity, materials

I'm trying to insert multiple materials into the object's submesh using the array, but I'm not getting
[image]
[image]

public GameObject[] obj;

```
//material mat;

public void Color(Material mat) {

    for (int x = 0; x < obj.Count; x++)
        obj[x].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials[1] = mat;

    Material[] mats = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
    mats[1] = mat;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = mats;

    {
        print("New Material");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Can you be more specific of what you are trying to do??

Comment: Your second attempt here — capturing a `mats` array, setting its entry at a particular index, then assigning the modified array back to the renderer — this looks correct. Is it not performing the way you expect? If not, can you explain in detail what you want it to do, and what behaviour you're observing instead?

Comment: from the material line [] mats, it's only 1 material for the respective element, so I'm trying to insert an array of materials, but I'm not getting

Comment: Please try to explain that in more detail.The language barrier here is making it difficult to understand what you mean. Maybe try editing your question to give an example of what you want the materials array to contain before your code runs, then show an example of what you want the array to contain after your code has run. Then we can see clearly what change you're trying to make.

Comment: I'm sorry, see if you can understand now.

Comment: "I'm trying to insert multiple materials" your code only shows you trying to assign one material. Where are these other materials of the "multiple" thar you're trying to insert? And with regard to the error in the screenshot, did you mean to use the array's `.Length` property? `.Count` is a member of a different type, the `List<T>`

Comment: It's a complicated topic if you want to combine meshes with multiple materials. Hope this can help - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6APzUgckV7U . But from your code it looks like you just want to set some material to second slot. You have compile errors, fixing them should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
material mat; 
GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().sharedMaterials [1] = mat; 
Material[] mats = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials; 
mats[1] = mat; 
GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = mats;
```

First error: The class "Material" should be in capital letters.  (your code shouldnt compile)

Second error:

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().sharedMaterials [1] = mat;
```

doesnt do anything.
You can not assign that material like this.

The rest of your code looks correct.

1. Did you assign the "mat" in the inspector?
2. Does your mesh even have more than 1 submesh?
3. Do you even want to assign more than 1 material?
4. Whats the error ? Doesnt it compile? Null reference? Nothing happenes?
5. Does your mesh renderer get the materials or does it just look wrong in the 3d view?

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MaterialArraySetter : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material Material1;

    void Start ()
    {
        Material[] materialsArray = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
        materialsArray[1] = Material1;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = materialsArray;

    }

}
```

[image]

EDIT2:

You seem to have compiler errors.
[image]

Comment: type is because I'm trying to use an array of gameobject or of materials either, so the object receives the color
   
the script itself works like this, but with only one material settling on its due.

 material mat;
 GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().sharedMaterials [1] = mat;
       Material[] mats = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
       mats[1] = mat;
       GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = mats;  
    
I'm trying to insert an array of materials, but I can not

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: Do you really want to assign more than one material? is exactly that, I'm trying to set an array of material to assign several materials in the sub-mesh, but I'm not getting...  here are the errors https://i.imgur.com/KIVAw8Y.png

Comment: i edited my answer - again

Comment: My God, I'm very blind, I swear to you that I saw a Length kkk, thank you very much.